# How do I implement Sailfish version of Hadoop on my Computer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Sailfish is a version of Hadoop that is more efficient than regular Hadoop. I am confused on how I can implement this version of Hadoop from the following Github repo: https://github.com/sriramsrao/sailfish .

Comment: More efficient according to what? Does that repository even use MR2? Spark is more efficient than MapReduce, if that's what you're considering

Answer (score 0):

Doe, I see the repository you have mentioned is too old. Even the last commit was 6 years before. Since there the world has moved quite far. I would suggest you to take a look at latest version of Hadoop from Hortonworks, Cloudera or MapR. I am sure they would be much more faster and well maintained than the one you have mentioned. 
Hope this helps !